# php/mysql: select from table and update in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'd like to know whether it is possible / advisable (why?), to select data from a table and update the same entry in the same pass

Example

```
 SELECT message_content, message_times_read FROM messages WHERE message_id = 1
```

Then

```
UPDATE messages SET message_times_read = message_times_read + 1 WHERE message_id = 1
```

Can I do them in one call? More importantly, if this is possible, should I? (i.e. is this considered proper practice, is this compatible across different versions, is there performance benefit?)

Comment: Some databases do support this kind of thing, e.g. [PostgreSQL's `UPDATE RETURNING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html). But as far as I know MySQL does not.

Comment: what you can do is to run the select query first and when that has fetched the row, you can put it in a variable and use that variable to run the update query. This usually happens very fast so ur user might not notice.

Comment: Put the two queries in a transaction so that another process can't get in between them.

Comment: Yes. It's possible - well, depending on what one means by 'one call'. No. It's not advisable.

Comment: @Strawberry: why is it not advisable?

Answer (score 0):

You must to create a Trigger if you want to do multiples queries in a same query. Check this link if you want to lear more about it: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/

Comment: I don't think you _must_ use triggers. What about stored procedures? Transactions?

Comment: If I understood correctly, this doesn't achieve what I want. There doesn't seem to be a way to fetch the data this way. Did I miss something?